# Kotlin non-null assertion with safe operator

Tags: kotlin

Why this code is giving me the NPE error?

```
fun main() {
    val myObj: MyObj? = null
    print(myObj?.someVal!!)
}

class MyObj{
    val someVal = 1
}
```

Does non-null assertion evaluate the whole expression before? I thought that `myObj?` should be enough to print null here.

Comment: I think it is same as doing (myObj?.someVal)!! so actually you are trying to null!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When you use a null-safe call, the expression is evaluated to null if the receiver is null, so

```
myObj?.someVal!!
```

behaves the same as

```
(if (myObj != null) myObj.someVal else null)!!
```

(If `myObj` is a property rather than local variable, these aren't equivalent, since smart-casting wouldn't work.)

Comment: "it's the same as myObj!!.someVal" False if `myObj` is not null, but `myObj.someVal` is; then `myObj!!.someVal` is null, and `myObj?.someVal!!` throws.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple example**:

This code will print null:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myObj: MyObj? = null
    val someVal = myObj?.someVal
    print(someVal)
}
```

This code will throw NPE as the variable is null:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myObj: MyObj? = null
    val someVal = myObj?.someVal
    print(someVal!!)
}
```